# Tunnel Connection Expo reload bug

Tags: react-native, mobile, expo, connection, ngrok

I'm running my `Expo` application with the command `"npx expo start -c --tunnel"` and every time, after 5 minutes of the application being open, a connection error occurs involving `Ngrok` and the tunnel connection with the error: `"Tunnel connection has been closed. This is often related to intermittent connection problems with the Ngrok servers. Restart the dev server to try connecting to Ngrok again."`